# Hyperledger fabric customising orderers for channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have existing hyperledger fabric setup with 2 organisations, 5 orderers and 1 channel, I want to create a new channel and want to make only 3 orderers (out of 5) as part of the new channel, for that I have mentioned the orderer details on channel profile section as follow:

```
NewChannel:
    Consortium: SampleConsortium
    <<: *ChannelDefaults
    Capabilities:
        <<: *ChannelCapabilities
    Orderer:
        <<: *OrdererDefaults
        OrdererType: etcdraft
        EtcdRaft:
            Consenters:
            - Host: orderer3.example.com
              Port: 13050
              ClientTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer3.example.com/tls/server.crt
              ServerTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer3.example.com/tls/server.crt
            - Host: orderer4.example.com
              Port: 14050
              ClientTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer4.example.com/tls/server.crt
              ServerTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer4.example.com/tls/server.crt
            - Host: orderer5.example.com
              Port: 15050
              ClientTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer5.example.com/tls/server.crt
              ServerTLSCert: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer5.example.com/tls/server.crt
        Addresses:
            - orderer3.example.com:13050
            - orderer4.example.com:14050
            - orderer5.example.com:15050
        Organizations:
            - *OrdererOrg
        Capabilities:
            <<: *OrdererCapabilities
    Application:
        <<: *ApplicationDefaults
        Organizations:
            - *Org1
            - *Org2
        Capabilities:
            <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

I have created channel transaction file without any issue by using `-channelCreateTxBaseProfile` argument but while creating the channel I'm getting following error:

> Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error validating channel
> creation transaction for new channel 'channel11', could not
> successfully apply update to template configuration: error authorizing
> update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Value]
> /Channel/OrdererAddresses not satisfied: implicit policy evaluation
> failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of
> the 'Admins' sub-policies to be satisfied

I'm not able to identify the exact issue with policy, can any one advise about the issue and how to resolve it.

Comment: I have an question,if you use `-channelCreateTxBaseProfile`,It will create an insecuresolo channel tx,I think you shuould use `-profile` newchanel

Comment: I'm using `-channelCreateTxBaseProfile` to specifies the orderer system channel profile along with `-profile`

Answer (score 0):

try to use orderer admin msp instead of peer admin msp

when you update channel config ,set env like these :

```
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="OrdererMSP"
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=${PROJECT_PATH}/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=${PROJECT_PATH}/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/users/Admin@example.com/msp
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
```

Comment: even configuring the orderer admin msp still getting the same error.